# R: how to add variable as parameter in aw_weight() function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to pass in a variable in aw_weight() function in R. (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/areal/versions/0.1.7/topics/aw_weight)

For example:

```
aw_weight(intersect, areaVar = "area", totalVar = "totalArea", areaWeight = "areaWeight")
```

Instead of pass in a variable to areaWeight instead of a string:

```
for (n in c("1","2","3")){
   aw_weight(intersect, areaVar = "area", totalVar = "totalArea", areaWeight = paste0(areaWeight, n))
}
```

But this does not work. It will name the "*areaWeight*" column as " paste0(areaWeight, n) " instead of "areaWeight1" ,  "areaWeight2" ,  "areaWeight3" which I want.

Thanks in advance for answering!!

Comment: If you use dput(head(intersect)) do provide some data to work with we can help you more easily.